# Empty lot & lof if I compile the toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I am finishing my PhD thesis and I stumbled over an odd bug. Sorry that I can't really post a MWE as this only occurs in a certain situation.

I use \includeonly in my document to fasten the compiling time whenever I work on a certain chapter. This is my preamble. \input{Einstellungen} loads all the packages etc. that I am using.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.9cm,right=2.1cm,twoside]{geometry} 
\raggedbottom 
\input{Einstellungen}
\input{Makros}
\includeonly{ 
    Kapitel/Deckblatt,
    Kapitel/Zitat,
    Kapitel/Kurzzusammenfassung,
    Kapitel/Abstract, 
    Kapitel/Literaturnachweise, 
    Kapitel/Inhaltsverzeichnis, %<------This is the toc
    Kapitel/ASE,
    Kapitel/Einleitung,
    Kapitel/Kapitel_1,
    Kapitel/Kapitel_2,
    Kapitel/Kapitel_3,
    Kapitel/Kapitel_4,
    Kapitel/Kapitel_5,
    Kapitel/Zusammenfassung,
    Kapitel/Literaturverzeichnis,
    Kapitel/Anhang,
    Kapitel/Danksagung,
    Kapitel/Versicherung
    }
```

and this is my main document

```
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\include{Kapitel/Deckblatt}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\include{Kapitel/Zitat}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\include{Kapitel/Kurzzusammenfassung}

\include{Kapitel/Abstract}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\include{Kapitel/Literaturnachweise}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

%This is the toc
\include{Kapitel/Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
        
\include{Kapitel/ASE}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungen und Symbole}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, title=Abk{\"u}rzungen]
\printglossary[type=symbolslist, style=symbunitlong]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Elemente und Materialien}
\printglossary[type=mater,style=long]
\newpage    
    
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\include{Kapitel/Einleitung}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Kapitel_1}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Kapitel_2}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Kapitel_3}
\newpage    

\include{Kapitel/Kapitel_4}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Kapitel_5}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Zusammenfassung}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Literaturverzeichnis}
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Anhang}
\newpage
    
\pagestyle{empty}                         
\include{Kapitel/Danksagung}
\newpage    

%This is the lof
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\listfigurename}
\begingroup
\sloppy
\raggedright
\listoffigures
\endgroup

%This is the lot
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\listtablename}
\begingroup
\sloppy
\raggedright
\listoftables
\endgroup
\newpage

\include{Kapitel/Versicherung}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

When I compile it like this I always get an empty lot and lof (see attached images)
[image: empty lof][image: empt lot]

Now because I use \includeonly I was able to find out that the bug only occurs when I include the tableofcontent. When I comment out the \includeonly{Kapitel/Inhaltsverzeichnis} part (wich means tableofcontent) everything works out just fine. I've tried every possible combination and it always comes back to the toc. As you can see I already tried to include the lof and lot in the main document because I thought it might be an issue with the \includeonly option. I tried this with the toc as well, but nothing changed. Everytime I use the toc the lot and lof turns out empty.

Here are all my preamble packages I use (sorry for the mess)

```
\usepackage{afterpage} %Kann leere Seiten erstellen
\usepackage{setspace} %ändert den Zeileabstand im Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} %Erzeugt Kommentare mittels \todo{} in der .pdf
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{notoccite} %Damit Zitate im Abbildungskapitel nicht die Reihenfolge versauen
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Package für Kopf- und Fußzeilen
    \pagestyle{fancyplain} % Kopfzeilen definieren
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter \hspace{3mm}#1}{}}
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
        \cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
        \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\small\sl\thepage}]
        {\fancyplain{}{\small\sl\leftmark}}
        \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\small\sl\rightmark}]
        {\fancyplain{}{\small\sl\thepage}}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{suffix} %Gehört irgendwie mit zu {acronym}
\usepackage{xstring} %Gehört irgendwie mit zu {acronym}
\usepackage{relsize} %Gehört irgendwie mit zu {acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Ich glaube, damit man Grafiken adden kann. Und für Tabellen
    \graphicspath{{./Images/}} %Unterordner Images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} %Für farbige Tabellen
    \definecolor{myOrange}{HTML}{ed7d31}
    \definecolor{myRed}{HTML}{d60000}
    \definecolor{myYellow}{HTML}{ffc000}
\usepackage{array} %Für Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} %Für komplexe Tabellen
\usepackage{subcaption} %Mehre Bilder nebeneinander
\usepackage{epstopdf} %package to overcome problem with eps in pdf files
%\usepackage{cite} %Damit man mit Citavi zitieren kann. Wird mit Biblatex nicht benötigt
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2215}{/} %Behebung eines random Fehlers wo "/" nicht erkannt wurde
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}% u. a. für \captionof
    \captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\usepackage{mwe}    
\usepackage{float} %Wichtig um die floats von Bildern und Tabellen zu ändern
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %Für Formeln
\usepackage{amsmath} %Für Formeln
\usepackage{mathtools} %Für Formeln
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
    % Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
    % and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
    % starred version does not.
    \makeatletter
    \let\oldabs\abs
    \def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
    \let\oldnorm\norm
    \def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
    \makeatother
\usepackage{color,soul}

%Glossaries----------------------------------
\usepackage[
nopostdot,      %kein Punkt hinten
nonumberlist, %keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,      %ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
%toc,          %Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
nogroupskip,    %kein Abstand zwischen 
section]      %im Inhaltsverzeichnis auf section-Ebene erscheinen
{glossaries}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{.75\columnwidth}} %für Zeilenumbrüche im Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage{xassoccnt} %Damit man Seiten zählen kann
    \newcounter{realpage}
    \DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{realpage}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \stepcounter{realpage}
    }
    
\newglossary[mlg]{mater}{myi}{myg}{Elemente und Materialien}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbole}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries {Kapitel/ASE.tex}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.15\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{10.5cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \\
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %to automatically adjust the width
& \glsunit{##1}% Description
& \glossentrydesc{##1}  
\tabularnewline
}
}


%Alle globalen document settings hier rein-----------------------------------------------
\setlength\parindent{0pt} %Wenn man keine Indentation haben möchte einfahc auf 0 setzen
\onehalfspacing %Zeilenabstand des Dokuments
\pagestyle{fancy} %Seitenzahlen abwechselnd rechts/links im header

%Literaturverzeichnis mit Biblatex/biber-----------------------------------------------
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}  %für biblatex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxnames=20, style=nature, autocite=superscript, isbn=false, intitle=true, url=false, doi=false, natbib=true, eprint=false]{biblatex}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 
\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis.bib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} %Literaturverzeichnis mit Citavi; (plain, unsrt, abbrv, alpha)
%\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis}

\makeatother %???
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Integriert Kapitelnummer in Formeln

%Commands hier rein
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %Alles was mit Hyperlinks zu tun hat
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = black,
        anchorcolor = blue,
        citecolor = blue,
        filecolor = blue,
        urlcolor = blue
        }
        \addto\extrasngerman{\def\subsectionautorefname{Kapitel}} %Definition "Kapitel" bei autoref von subsection  
        \addto\extrasngerman{\def\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}} %Definition "Kapitel" bei autoref von section
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

Yeah so maybe you can help me and see my error here. If it helps I could send the whole files but as it's a PhD Thesis it is huge^^

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Off-topic: Don't run `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}`; instead, run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to maximize the interoperability between the two packages. Also, since you load `xcolor`, there can be no good reason for loading `color` as well. A final general exhortation: don't load packages (e.g., `setspace`) more than once.

Comment: sorry but you will have to spent some time to make a MWE.  And if I may say so: it is not really difficult, as you only need a few small dummy files and then try if your main file still shows the issue.

Comment: @Mico we hope that the next versions of the packages will remove this requirement.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - That would be a very nice touch indeed. :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So far I was not able to reproduce this bug within a MWE

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the clearification. I will have a look at the packages and get them in order :)

Comment: `\afterpage{\null\newpage}` looks very wrong `\include` always does a `\clearpage` so you should not need `\newpage` and definitely do not need `\afterpage`.  Do not `\include` your `\tableofcontents`,  `\input` it.